# Download images api python

Tags: python

I have a simple code
What I want is to download the images from the api, but it doesn't download them

```
import requests

url = "https://www.habbo.es/extradata/public/users/hhes-aafb213bbe8a70df33faa0259cfb5f33/photos"
data = requests.get(url).json()

for key in data:
    print(data[0]["url"])
```

How could I download all the images to a folder?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just printing the image URL. You need to write the image contents to a file, that's how you can download them. There are also other methods like using wget library too. But here is how you can do it as well:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.habbo.es/extradata/public/users/hhes-aafb213bbe8a70df33faa0259cfb5f33/photos"
data = requests.get(url).json()
for key in data:
    image_url = 'https:' + key['url']
    response = requests.get(image_url)
    filename = data[0]['url'].split("/")[-1]
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Try now. I have updated the code. The scheme was missing from your link